# matrix multiplication in a multithreading way

Tags: c, multithreading

Hi Im trying to teach myself multithreading by working the following exercise: multiply two hardcoded matrixes,  matrix1 and matrix2, and save the result in matrix3. The strategy is to assign one thread for the calculation of each element in the result matrix (matrix3).

Though the program is runnable, but the result is not right. Any enlightenments why the result is wrong? Thanks!

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "thread.h"

void *multiply(void *arguments);

#define X 2
#define Y 2
#define Z 3

int matrix1[X][Y] = {{0, 1}, {2, 3}};
int matrix2[Y][Z] = {{4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
int matrix3[X][Z];

struct arguments_combo
{
    int rowIdxInMatrix1;
    int colIdxInMatrix2;
};

int main()
{
    thread_t threads[X * Z];

    for (int rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < X; rowIdx++)
    {
        for (int colIdx = 0; colIdx < Z; colIdx++)
        {
            struct arguments_combo arguments;
            arguments.rowIdxInMatrix1 = rowIdx;
            arguments.colIdxInMatrix2 = colIdx;
            pthread_create(&(threads[rowIdx * Z + colIdx]), NULL, multiply, (void *)&arguments);
        }
    }

    for (int rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < X; rowIdx++)
    {
        for (int colIdx = 0; colIdx < Z; colIdx++)
        {
            void *val_ptr;
            pthread_join(threads[rowIdx * Z + colIdx], &val_ptr);
            int *cur_val_ptr = (int *)val_ptr;
            printf("The rowIdx: %d and colIdx: %d and the val: %d\n", rowIdx, colIdx, *cur_val_ptr);
            matrix3[rowIdx][colIdx] = *cur_val_ptr;
            free(cur_val_ptr);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void *multiply(void *arguments)
{
    struct arguments_combo *data_ptr = (struct arguments_combo *)arguments;

    int rowIdxInMatrix1 = data_ptr->rowIdxInMatrix1;
    int colIdxInMatrix2 = data_ptr->colIdxInMatrix2;
    int *sum = malloc(sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < Y; i++)
    {
        *sum += matrix1[rowIdxInMatrix1][i] * matrix2[i][colIdxInMatrix2];
    }

    pthread_exit((void *)sum);
    return NULL;
}
```

**Output**

```
The rowIdx: 0 and colIdx: 0 and the val: 9
The rowIdx: 0 and colIdx: 1 and the val: 29
The rowIdx: 0 and colIdx: 2 and the val: 29
The rowIdx: 1 and colIdx: 0 and the val: 34
The rowIdx: 1 and colIdx: 1 and the val: 39
The rowIdx: 1 and colIdx: 2 and the val: 39
```

Comment: Maybe rip out the threading initially, until you have a working serial version.  Then convert that to a threaded version.  "Premature optimization is the root of all evil".

Comment: BTW, why use void *?  Shouldn't you use the type system to assist you?

Comment: I think there a Strassen mutrix multiplication algorithm already in place. You can use that algorithm to reduce time complexity. It is based on parallel processing.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strassens-matrix-multiplication/

Comment: The whole point here of using multithreading is just for the practice rather than optimizing the matrix multiplication efficiency. But yeah, I like the quote "Premature optimization is the root of evil" :). Thank you guys for the comments anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I am not an expert of this subject just tried to correct it. Seems like the cause is this part

```
struct arguments_combo arguments;
arguments.rowIdxInMatrix1 = rowIdx;
arguments.colIdxInMatrix2 = colIdx;
pthread_create(&(threads[rowIdx * Z + colIdx]), NULL, multiply, (void *)&arguments);
```

Could be wrong, but I think there is a race condition here. You gave this single `arguments` variable address to all thread, but you also overwrite it later on so when a thread accessing it likely having some other value already.

If you create an args array like this `struct arguments_combo args[X * Z];` at global scope and you change your code also to this:

```
args[rowIdx * Z + colIdx].rowIdxInMatrix1 = rowIdx;
args[rowIdx * Z + colIdx].colIdxInMatrix2 = colIdx;
pthread_create(&(threads[rowIdx * Z + colIdx]), NULL, multiply, (void *)&args[rowIdx * Z + colIdx]);
```

Then the result seems valid in this case

```
The rowIdx: 0 and colIdx: 0 and the val: 7
The rowIdx: 0 and colIdx: 1 and the val: 8
The rowIdx: 0 and colIdx: 2 and the val: 9
The rowIdx: 1 and colIdx: 0 and the val: 29
The rowIdx: 1 and colIdx: 1 and the val: 34
The rowIdx: 1 and colIdx: 2 and the val: 39
```

Although sometimes it will give still random values. The reason is that you do not initialize `*sum` to `0` in `multiply` function so don't forget to do it also and than everything seems to be working fine.

Comment: Ohh this is very helpful and thanks for the sharing! There are still two questions: 1. Why the variable `arguments` address is the same across different iterations of for loop? 2. Could you please explain more about the `*sum` initialization? it should happen before or after I call the `malloc`? Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @RoseBoy 2) after malloc 1) Because it will allocated on the same address on the stack..it just...stack things you know. Not the most solid answer I know. https://godbolt.org/z/XpNTar check this and you see that the assembly of the body of the for loop is the same so actually `k` will be on the same address in each iteration.

Comment: 1. yea I run LLDB for the debugging and see the address of `arguments` is always the same across the different iterations......I thought once `arguments` is 'destroyed'  after each iteration, it will be 'created' at a different address in the next iteration but its the same address. 2. check this video at 8:42 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9uhSYDY4sxA&t=522s) He doesn't initialize the pointer and I wonder why

Comment: You dont need if you overwirte it anyway with a new value which does not depend on the current value, but in your code you use it like `*sum += ...` so you actually adding to its current value so if it was some garbage value than you are in trouble if your code were like `*sum = some_value` then there would not need to initialize it since you setting the value to a concrete new value. It not about pointer but the way you sum so if you would have a normal variable like `int sum` you should initialize that too to 0 to avoid this problem wit `sum+= ...`

Comment: I see. The main reason here for initialization is `*sum += ...` rather than setting it a new value. Thank you very much & you're just amazed at teaching!